# Bootstrap div placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="img.png" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row"><p>Main text</p></div>
        <div class="row"><p>More...</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need this result:

[image]

So I need a picture which takes up 50% of the screen width and then a big title which is centered horizontally, but vertically is on top; and "more..." text which is to the right horizontally, but on the bottom vertically. How do I manage to do this? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution: use display flex to make both columns have same height, then use position relative ad absolute to position your columns

```css
.title{
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.title h1{
  width: 100%;
  }

.description{
  background-color: yellow;
}

/*NEW*/
.row{
  display:flex;/*makes col have same height*/
  }

.details{
  position: relative !important;
  }

.description{
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0;
  }

.description p{
  width: 100%;
text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150/150" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 details">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 title">
          <h1>Main text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 description">
          <p>More...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "main text" should be aligned to center
"more..." should be aligned right
It doesn't seem to work... Why?

Comment: now main text is aligned to center and more is aligned to the right

Comment: in my code, I see you edited the css above, and now it seems to work

Comment: I would not use flexbox. This is not compatible in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you mean?

```css
.title{
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.description{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150/150" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 details">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 title">
          <h1>Main text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 description">
          <p>More...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I need the "more..." text not to be sticked to the main text, but to be vertically aligned to bottom with the picture...